# How can I get root or TWRP without being able to enter any recovery?

Tags: recovery-mode, custom-roms, twrp, sony-xperia-z2

I have a phone running Android Marshmallow (6) and apps constantly crash. Most apps I would like to use do not support Android 6. I would like to update to a custom ROM or a newer version.

- adb and fastboot work
- fastboot mode and recovery mode do not work
- the device does not have too

How can I proceed? I find it's sort of chicken and egg problem with no recovery and no root. To be clear, I can't even get into stock recovery. The phone is Xperia Z2. Flashtool works but I can't find any newer versions of FTF files.

Comment: Some of the steps may be relevant: [{Root}{Sony Xperia Z2}{MM}{23.5.A.0.575} unlock bootloader, root and ROM flashing](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/root-sony-xperia-z2-mm-23-5-a-0-575-unlock-bootloader-root-and-rom-flashing.3420744/)

Comment: read about [FOTAkernel](https://twrp.me/sony/sonyxperiaz2.html) and get help on official [support thread on xda-developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2772879)

Comment: There are constant notifications that an app has stopped working. Any idea how I can stop these so that it's easier to work on the phone to get root? I had to dirty flashing a FTF and think these errors happen because the version of Android is older and doesn't support them.

Comment: You can ignore those message or perform a factory reset. When unlocking the bootloader a factory reset will be performed anyway.

Comment: Is there a way to backup the apps and (more importantly) their data using adb without root?